# Assembly conflicts after NuGet update

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, assemblies, azure-webjobs

I have a .Net Framework 4.7.1 Web Forms app and .Net Framework 4.7.1. WebJob, both running on Azure AppService.

Since updating via Nuget WebJob packages from 2.0.0 to 2.2.0 a number of dependency issues occurred.

First one comes up at runtime:

`System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference`

Second one shows during compilation:

`Consider app.config remapping of assembly` for a number of assemblies like System.Net.Http, System.Net.Sockets, System.IO.Compression, etc.

To solve this, advised by number of sources and compiler warning I have added

```
<PropertyGroup>
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
<GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This has allowed for WebJob execution but still compiler shows warning on assembly remapping.

I have seen more issues regarding assembly conflicts since as I believe .Net Standard.

Can you please explain to me
1. What is going on with assemblies and why I need to turn on Binding Redirects?
2. Why this does not solve the second issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What is going on with assemblies and why I need to turn on Binding Redirects?

It [requires assembly binding redirects](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481) that need to be generated during the build process. And after you add this to your webjobs, it will add assembly into bin folder when you build.

> 2. Why this does not solve the second issue?

It seems that it is a VS issue, you could solve it by click `Migrate packages.config to PackageReference` in your webjob References. Add the following .csproj in your webjobs and compiled.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1544).